# AVAudioPlayer cannot be initialized

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios, avaudioplayer

In a Xamarin.iOS Application `AVAudioPlayer` is used to record and play some audio files.

The user records and saves some audio files very fast and when he tries to play one of them it throws a System.Exception in the line:

```
NSError error;
_player = new AVAudioPlayer(NSUrl.FromFilename(_audioPlaybackFilePath), "m4a", out error);
```

> System.Exception: Could not initialize an instance of the type
>   'AVFoundation.AVAudioPlayer': the native
>   'initWithContentsOfURL:fileTypeHint:error:' method returned nil. It is
>   possible to ignore this condition by setting
>   MonoTouch.ObjCRuntime.Class.ThrowOnInitFailure to false.

The file in the given path exists.

1. Any indications of what the problem might be?
2. Is there any way to set  MonoTouch.ObjCRuntime.Class.ThrowOnInitFailure to false as it states in the Exception StackTrace?

Comment: **`method returned nil`** : Your `NSUrl` is not returning a valid file that can be use to create a `AVAudioPlayer`

Comment: The thing is that the file exists (`File.Exists` returns true with the given path. Only rarely returns false!). So should I just wrap the initialization of `AVAudioPlayer` into try catch? Is there a way to verify that the file is valid before  I initialize the `AVAudioPlayer`?

Comment: In some fashion yes... if the file is still being flushed to "disk" and closed by Mono and thus iOS (whether this is due to multi-threaded user code or via iOS) and you are trying to open it (via AVAudioPlayer) the error makes sense. You could introduce some retry logic that checks if the file exists and if it does, check that is not zero bytes and can be opened in an exclusive lock, etc... before using `AVAudioPlayer.FromUrl`.

Comment: Personally I would use `AVAudioPlayer.FromData` as if you are going to do the file exist check, size check and load lock test, you might as well use the data  (`NSData`) to create your AVAudioPlayer instance

Comment: Have you tried   `_player = new AVAudioPlayer(new NSUrl(_audioPlaybackFilePath), "m4a", out error);`?

Comment: @SushiHangover the file was empty but the length was 32. So what i did to to just wrap the call into a try catch block and throw an `InvalidDataException`. Another way would be to check for the length of the file if it is equal or less than 32. But since It was kind of a magic number approach I avoided it

Comment: @ColeXia it returned the same `Exception`

Answer (score 0):

As @SushilHangover pointed out use AVAudioPlayer.FromData and feed it with a stream like:

```
    theStream.Position = 0;
    AVAudioPlayer.FromData(NSData.FromStream(theStream));
```

AND, this is very important, the stream has always be positioned to 0.

Answer (score 0):

We got this error using the package [Plugin.AudioRecorder](https://github.com/NateRickard/Plugin.AudioRecorder) which uses `AVAudioPlayer`. We could fix it by adding the following code to `FinishedLaunching`:

```
AudioPlayer.OnPrepareAudioSession = audioSession =>
{
    // maybe force audio to route to the speaker?
    var success = audioSession.OverrideOutputAudioPort (AVAudioSessionPortOverride.Speaker, out NSError error);
};
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, it was because I forgot to specify the extension of the file. The right way to do it (ie: for **mp3** files) is :

```
var soundResource = NSUrl.FromFilename("alert.mp3");
```

And not

```
var soundResource = NSUrl.FromFilename("alert");
```